# Strange alignment issue

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm new to HTML and CSS and building my first site. I'm coming across this very strange alignment and positioning issue and has stumped me. I would appreciate anybody helping me understand what's going on.

I've loaded the html and css to codepen so you can view it: http://codepen.io/joe/pen/kJmeK

I also took a screenshot of the problem and uploaded it for your viewing: [image: http://i46.tinypic.com/wt850g.jpg]

What's happening is that as soon as I wrap the phone number and the address lines 1-3 in a `p` tag, they seem to get right-aligned and get stuck under the map. But as soon as I unwrap them they go back to their original location and behave normally.

However, loaded into codepen the `p` tags seem to be behaving as they should.

I've tried to address this by playing with negative margins and paddings in CSS for both the `h2` tags and the `p` tags. But that creates the problem of not knowing where the `<p>`s are exactly located and aligning them with the contact_us form.

As you can see in my CSS, I have not played with the `p` tags anywhere else previously.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's best to just post your code in the OP itself and include a demo if needed.  Otherwise, this question will be useless to others after the links go dead.

Comment: try p {float:right;} or left

Comment: Btw, you have an extra `"` on line 48: `<td valign="top"">`

Comment: And on line 37 you have this: `</tr>`, but there's no starting `<tr>` anywhere

Comment: Based on what @yentup is seeing, I think you need to put the HTML through the W3C Validator.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What exactly do you want the end result to look like?

Comment: Hi yentup. Thanks for your help. Truth be told I downloaded the contact_us form and the associated PHP script from a site. I went back to the source and I saw those errors were in the original file. But I corrected them in my own code. As far as what I'm trying to achieve, well nothing too fancy! I just want the tel #, address lines and form labels to all be indented and aligned. I would like to change font style and weight for all three if possible. But I would have liked very much to know what's causing this behaviour to prevent future headaches. Thanks again!

Comment: Sparky, I will try to post the code in the OP as you suggested. Also, thanks for pointing out the Validator. I didn't know about it. I'm sure it'll be very handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

youre code is pretty messy from what i can tell. If youre gonna use tables, why bother with absolute positioning for this simple layout?

Most likely, maps, has float right, p, doesnt have any float property and is thus positioned behind the map, because a floated element is taken out of the normal flow of elements.

```
p {float:left;}
```

or

```
p {float:right;}
```

should do the trick, but still i would suggest reviewing youre whole code, and making either a table layout, or better yet a css layout not using any tables for layout.

Also note, a floated element should have a width propperty set as well, otherwise, it shrink wraps.